# Saving JSON in phonegap/cordova and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, jquery-mobile, cordova

While this question is asked many times in different versions, I have not yet managed to get a clear view as what is a good solution to save a returned *json* file so it can be used later on the application.

I am using *phonegap* in combination with *JQuery Mobile*, I fetch the data as *jsonp* and I want to save the returned data, in a storage mechanism so I can use that data in my code.

Any ideas, or code are welcomed :)

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html ?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options in hand

### Phone's sqlite storage

PhoneGap provides you with API to access the sqlite db. So you can just store the JSON as it is in the storage and retrieve it when you want it back.

Check this [documentation on how to do this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

### HTML5 Storage methods

All browsers that supports html5 do supports sessionStorage and localStorage. Basic different between these two are is that sessionStorage available in only during the session but localStorage is available as long as browser cache available.

You can store data to sessionStorage or localStorage as below

```
sessionStorage.myJSONString = '{"name":"Kumar", "age":"22"}'
```

Read more about [html5 storage here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: Are there any differences in efficiency, speed? My json will be quite a long set of values...

Comment: @DaimanLoks I have not done any benchmarks but I don't think there would be much difference. But make sure to check the max length you can store on `sqlite` and `webstorage`.